# How to get the files inside a directory link with python

Tags: python, windows, symlink, shortcut-file

This is probably super easy, but after an hour of trying, I haven't been able to find it.

From a specific folder inside a database called `/Database/Images/`, I manually created a folder link with Windows and placed it at, `/Tests/Images`.

With that done, I created a python script inside the `/Tests` folder and I'm trying to use it to access the files inside that `/Tests/Images` link.

How can I get the data inside `/Database/Images/` from the link `/Tests/Images`?

The problem is that I can't use `os.listdir()`, because it is not a directory, but I also can't seem to find the way to know that  `/Tests/Images` is actually pointing to `/Database/Images/`

So far I've tried several `os` function but

- `os.listdir()` returns that `/Tests/Images` is not a directory
- `os.path.islink()` returns False
- `os.path.realpath()` and `os.path.abspath()` returns `/Tests/Images`, not `/Database/Images/`

Comment: you say "database", but is this really a _network filesystem_? are you using WSL2? what process did you use to create the "folder link"?

Comment: Are these folders in an NTFS file tree, or within a WSL mount?

If you're on NTFS and you can switch to a junction instead of a symbolic link, you should be able to follow the link as if it was a regular directory entry.

Comment: Exactly what kind of "folder link" is this, and how did you create it?